# bash: /python/run/venv/bin/activate: No such file or directory

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm trying to deploy my django app through AWS elastic beanstalk, & I've been running into an issue for the past 2 days which i've narrowed down more.

A command in the deployment process is failing, this command is as follows:

```
container_commands:
  01_migrate:
    command: "python3 manage.py migrate"
    leader_only: true
```

The section of the AWS EB console logs that tell me this refer me to cfn-init.log, checking this tells me the same thing. In cfn-init-cmd.log however, i see this

```
2020-06-19 18:24:24,753 P5019 [INFO] Command 01_migrate
2020-06-19 18:24:24,771 P5019 [INFO] -----------------------Command Output-----------------------
2020-06-19 18:24:24,771 P5019 [INFO]    Traceback (most recent call last):
2020-06-19 18:24:24,771 P5019 [INFO]      File "manage.py", line 10, in main
2020-06-19 18:24:24,771 P5019 [INFO]        from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
2020-06-19 18:24:24,771 P5019 [INFO]    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django'
2020-06-19 18:24:24,771 P5019 [INFO]
2020-06-19 18:24:24,771 P5019 [INFO]    The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
2020-06-19 18:24:24,771 P5019 [INFO]
2020-06-19 18:24:24,772 P5019 [INFO]    Traceback (most recent call last):
2020-06-19 18:24:24,772 P5019 [INFO]      File "manage.py", line 21, in <module>
2020-06-19 18:24:24,772 P5019 [INFO]        main()
2020-06-19 18:24:24,772 P5019 [INFO]      File "manage.py", line 16, in main
2020-06-19 18:24:24,772 P5019 [INFO]        ) from exc
2020-06-19 18:24:24,772 P5019 [INFO]    ImportError: Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you forget to activate a virtual environment?
```

Leading me to believe the issue is with my virtual environment failing to activate. Some research online tells me the command to activate venv should be

```
opt/python/run/venv/bin/activate
```

i've tried to activate this through eb ssh, with no luck, getting the message

```
bash: opt/python/run/venv/bin/activate: No such file or directory
```

when i check the opt directory, this is confirmed by a lack of a python folder, i've no idea why the virtual env isn't there/ isn't able to be activated and any help would be greatly appreciated

EDIT - directory structure:
parent directory - django microblog
[image]

.ebextensions - 
[image]

djangmicroblog - 
[image]

djangoportfolio (local virtualenv folder) - 
[image]

Comment: Can you show directory structure?

Comment: I've added some images of local directory structure, tree output was far too large to be readable

Answer (score 2):

Turns out my application was built for a mix between amazon linux 1 & 2, & the environment was amazon linux 2.

I had to downgrade my environment to AL1 python 3.6, and revert some of the settings in the application to AL1 (such as the wsgi path)

It's now up and running :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
container_commands:
  01_migrate:
    command: "/opt/python/run/venv/bin/python3 manage.py migrate"
    leader_only: true
```

Don't think in "activate it", simply run the python from your venv.

Comment: Gave that a go, deployment failed again :/
cfn-init-cmd.log reports:
[INFO] Test for Command 01_migrate
[INFO] Completed successfully.
[INFO] ============================================================
[INFO] Command 01_migrate
[INFO] -----------------------Command Output-----------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Exited with error code 127